# Conflicting jQuery

Tags: jquery, conflict

For my site, i wanted to use the template Prologue from html5up.net. This one has anchors, and clicking a menu item shows a smooth scroll to the right section of the page. the template is loading a jquery.min.js from a folder named "js". When i open this file it says jQuery v1.10.2.

In the page i wanted to use colorbox, which also loads jQuery 1.10.2 but then from Google.

So now my colorbox works perfectly, but because of adding the colorbox, the smooth scroll function does not work anymore, unless i remove the jQuery link to Google, but then the colorbox does not open "above" the rest of my site?

Anyone can tell me what i should change to keep both (scrolling and colorbox)?

Comment: Seems like you are loading jquery twice. Can you copy paste the relevant code also?

Comment: i am loading query twice. this i my head section : http://pastebin.com/yFB6czKp

Comment: Okay, have you tried by just adding one version of jquery alone at the beginning of your head. Next you can try using jquery.noConflict() and try using another variable for either scroll or colorbox

Comment: if i remove line 8, it won't scroll my page anymore. colorbox works as it should and opens in front of everything else (like the menu of the left side). if i remove line 14, the scrolling works, the colorbox opens, but the colorbox opens behind the left menubar?

Comment: Okay, remove line 14 and then try toggling the z-index of the colorbox div..You can make it work... Do u have a link to the same?..

Comment: Silly question but when you removed the top jquery, did you move the other scripts to below the second jquery? (ie the `skel.min.js`, etc)

Comment: no i did not move the other scripts. i can try that too. i just removed line 14 as test, and changed z-index of colorbox, but it stil shows up behind the menu bar. default z-index is 9999, and i tried 990, 90, 0, 1 and 10

Comment: ok, i removed line 8, so only line 14 loads jquery. then moved the other scripts like Pete said, scrolling works, but but colorbox opens behind menubar now?

Comment: Do u have a link to which we can take a look at?

Comment: for the site? no, i dont have a link yet. this is all the code i have now: http://pastebin.com/pxPhgvHv   . the colorbox starts at line 259

Comment: Sounds like a styling issue then, what is the z-index of the menu bar?

Comment: i checked all css files, but i cannot find any z-index for the menu :(

Answer (score 0):

As both version of JQuery are same, use JQuery once, I prefer the version of google cdn. so, for now please try as following.

1. Rearrange your code as http://pastebin.com/hBEGbguD
2. Try to use jquery.noConflict().

I think it will be enough to solve your problem

Thanks